# Does training step controls number of iterations in convolution neural network?

Tags: tensorflow

By using Convolution neural network I have to train 100000 samples and batch size is 100 where as training step is 4000. If I pass 100 samples for first time it will be considered as one iteration.I want to run code for 10000 iterations. If i set training step 1000 does it means that i complete 10000 iterations?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you are training your model, but most setups increment global step once per session.run call on your training ops, so setting training step to X and batch size to Y will lead to you doing X steps, each over Y examples, to a total of X*Y examples processed.